# How to work with maps in JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Here is the overview of a problem..

```
public class Student
{
  private Map<Test,MarkWrapper> marks;
  ...
}

public class MarkWrapper
{
  private List<Mark> marks;
  ...
}

public class Test
{
  private String name;
  private Date date;
  ..
}

public class Mark
{
  private int mark;
  private int total;
  private float average;
  ...
}
```

Now, I would like to retrieve students who got 90 marks. Rather than changing the architecture by removing the map, how to solve this problem?

In the Map class there is no getter method to get the values in it. If this can't be achieved then how would i do it with Criteria API?

Thank you.

Comment: By 'got 90 marks' you mean size of `Map<Test,MarkWrapper> marks`, size of `List<Mark> marks` or `int mark` equal to 90 ?

Comment: @wypieprz int mark=90;

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to retrieve students who got 90 marks

If you want to retrieve student whose marks is exact 90 then make your map key as *90* and add value as student.

Example:

*Pun on map to those students who got exact 90 marks by iterating studentList*

```
Map<Integer,Student> studentMap=new HashMap<Integer, Student>();
List<Student> studentList= <yourStudentList>;
for(Student student : studentList){
    if(student.getMarks() == 90){
        studentMap.put(90,student);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I assume you have entity class name as `Student` and have property `marks` and so on.

*Using JPQL:*

You can do to get students list from database either

```
String jpql="Select s from Student s where s.marks =:marks ";
Query query=em.createQuery(jpql);
query.setParameter("marks", 90);
List<Student> studentList=query.getResultList();//returns all students who got marks 90
```

or

```
String jpql="Select s from Student s ";
Query query=em.createQuery(jpql);
List<Student> studentList1=query.getResultList();//returns all students
```

and you can put in map to all students who got 90 marks by iterating studentList1 like I said earlier

Comment: I don't have a student list with me, what I all want is to retrieve those students who have 90 marks using JPQL or criteria API.

Comment: The `marks` field is of type `Map` but not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

An example JPQL query string:

```
SELECT s FROM Student s JOIN s.marks sm 
WHERE VALUE(sm) IN (
  SELECT mw FROM MarkWrapper mw JOIN mw.marks mwm 
  WHERE mwm.mark = :value
)
```

where `:value` is query parameter (i.e. 90)